# How to change shadedraw color

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

With, this code

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \shadedraw[shading=radial, color=blue] (0,0) circle (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I get this

[image]

But is it possible to change the color of the shading. I try `shading color=blue` but latex stops. I use lualatex but I think it does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       \shadedraw[shading=radial,
                 line width=3mm,
                 color=blue,
                 outer color=red,
                 inner color=yellow] (0,0) circle (4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I did not see the page in the TikZ in which there is that. Thanks.

Comment: @somenxavier Page 173 says "The shadings as well as additional shadings are described in more detail in Section 65". And in section 65 you'll find all these options.